# export_to_png() function of kivy gives error

Tags: python, kivy

I learnt that kivy supports `export_to_png(filename)` function which saves a widget and all its children to a given filename however when I am trying to achieve this I get an error.
See documentation link below

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.export_to_png

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Below is my sample code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyWidget(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = MyWidget()
        a = Button(text="hello")
        parent.add_widget(a)
        parent.export_to_png('a.png')
        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Errors which we receive on console are as follows :

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/Paarth/Google_Drive/Google Drive/Codes/Python/Work/kivy/kivyBasics/Screenshots_SaveImage.py", line 20, in 
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\kivy\app.py", line 766, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "D:/Paarth/Google_Drive/Google Drive/Codes/Python/Work/kivy/kivyBasics/Screenshots_SaveImage.py", line 15, in build
     parent.export_to_png('a.png')
 AttributeError: 'MyWidget' object has no attribute 'export_to_png'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: "I get an error" is never helpful whereas the _exact_ error message, preferably with any traceback produced, is nearly always.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor . Error which i am receiving is AttributeError: 'MyWidget' object has no attribute 'export_to_png'

Comment: Which version of Kivy are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export_to_png` was added to Kivy in 1.8.1, whereas it appears that you're using 1.8.0.

Try upgrading Kivy to the latest version.

Comment: looks like i missed included in 1.8.1 in the documentation ... I will try using screenshot() rather :)